# android Quinny898 PersistentSearch double line

Tags: android

Im trying to make to use Quinny898 PersistentSearch library (https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch). But when I use it inside android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout I get two line actionbar.

[Print screen of Two line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHMKn.png) .

Any help is appreciated :-)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch.SearchBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchbox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says,

> Please include this after any elements you wish to be hidden by it in
>   a releativelayout.

Try this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <ReleativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch.SearchBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </ReleativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```